# Goland how to change clicked text and its other usages' background color

Tags: ide, goland

[image]

It's really hard to see other usages of clicked text in Goland, so I want to change background colors of them (e.g. `someVar` in the pic I shared). I couldn't find the related setting in settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code | Identifier under caret" and you can change the Background color there. If you want to change the color for the current identifier where the cursor is, you can also change the "Identifier under caret (write)" from the same section.